# two vectors subtraction works but division returning single number and not vector

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB I have two vectors which are both 1 x 310 of type doubles.

So I have a line shown below. ret & bret are my vectors. This result produces another vector act_r of 1 X 310 of type double - all makes sense.

```
act_r = (ret - bret);
```

However when I try to divide every element in ret by its corresponding element in bret (again shown below) I get a single number. Why is this? How do I get Matlab to divide every element in ret by the corresponding element in bret?

```
act_d = (ret / bret);
```

Comment: thanks! See I have a lot of learning to do with Matlab!

Comment: Start from here, I would suggest - http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/operators-and-elementary-operations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB (the name comes from MATrix LABoratory) per default excutes matrix operation so `ret/bret` will be evaluated as a matrix operation:

```
x = B/A
```

uses the `mrdivide` operator (a overload of `/` ) which solves systems of linear equations xA = B for x hence returning a scalar.

while `x =A./B` uses the `rdivide` operator which divides each element of A by the corresponding element of B

more information [here](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html)